# Warning message: 29192 failed to parse in lubridate

Tags: r, parsing, lubridate

for eg:

```
asia$date<-ymd(asia$date)
```

output:
Warning message:  29192 failed to parse

date format in .csv file is "yy.dd.mm" throughout

Comment: use `ydm` in palce of `ymd`

Comment: it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated you have a date like

```
x <- c("09.01.01", "09.02.01", "09.03.01")
```

Then you can use

```
library(lubridate)
ydm(x)
```

returns me

```
#> [1] "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03"
```